# Appending JSONs together without modifying them

Tags: python, json

I have multiple JSON files which look like this:

`foo.json`:

```
{"Email":["abc@abc.com","aac@abc.com","asd@ac.com"]}
```

`bar.json`:

```
{"Work": ["Microsoft","Google","Yahoo"]}
```

I want to append all these together without modifying them:
I am using this for appending them:

```
 import json
 import glob
 import sys
 import os

 read_files = glob.glob("*.json")
 output_list = []

 for f in read_files:
     with open(f, "rb") as infile:
         output_list.append(json.load(infile))

 with open("merged_file.json", "wb") as outfile:
     json.dump(output_list, outfile)
```

The output of this is:

```
 [{"Email":["abc@abc.com","aac@abc.com","asd@ac.com"]},{"Work": ["Microsoft","Google","Yahoo"]}]
```

Which makes the output look different from the input. How can I not have the "[ ]" at the start and the end, with all keys in the same JSON object?

The desired output is:

```
{"Email":["abc@abc.com","aac@abc.com","asd@ac.com"],"Work": ["Microsoft","Google","Yahoo"]}
```

Comment: Without the array it's not valid JSON…

Comment: @deceze  this is also a valid json: `'{"Email": ["abc@abc.com", "aac@abc.com", "asd@ac.com"],"Work": ["Microsoft", "Google", "Yahoo"]}'`

Comment: @marmeladze But `{...},{...}` is not.

Comment: @deceze- You have any other way ?

Comment: @AnshajGoel: ah, see, you didn't tell us you wanted to create a single dictionary with the keys merged. What should happen if keys are not unique? Please be **explicit** about your output format here and your goal. I thought you wanted `{"Email":["abc@abc.com","aac@abc.com","asd@ac.com"]},{"Work": ["Microsoft","Google","Yahoo"]}`, which is two JSON objects with a comma between them.

Comment: @MartijnPieters- I want to use that file to get indexed in elasticsearch

Comment: @MartijnPieters- Sorry, I got confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are building a list, yet your expected output shows you want a JSON object (a dictionary in Python). Provided your input files have *unique keys*, you need to build a new dictionary:

```
import glob
import json

output = {}

for f in glob.glob("*.json"):
    with open(f, "rb") as infile:
        entry = json.load(infile)
        output.update(entry)

with open("merged_file.jsonl", "wb") as outfile:
    json.dump(output, outfile)
```

Comment: What changes do I make apart from "rb" to "r" when I use it in python3 ?

Comment: @anshaj: Use `'w'` instead of `'wb'` when writing.